# Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type AccountController, key \"\""

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

That's my `AccountController`:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private UserManager<User> _userManager { get; set; }

    public AccountController() : this(new UserManager<User>(new UserStore())) {}

    public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager) {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

And stack trace:

```
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type AccountController, key ""
  Source=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 53
       at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType) in c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 34
       at System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.DelegateBasedDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type)
  InnerException: StructureMap.StructureMapException
       HResult=-2146232832
       Message=StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[[Fables.BLL.Entities.User, Fables.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
       Source=StructureMap
       ErrorCode=202
       StackTrace:
            at StructureMap.BuildSession.<.ctor>b__0(Type t) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 33
            at StructureMap.Util.Cache`2.get_Item(KEY key) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Util\Cache.cs:line 83
            at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 215
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.DefaultInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\DefaultInstance.cs:line 22
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 103
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 69
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Get(String propertyName, Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorInstance.cs:line 74
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Get[T](String propertyName, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorInstance.cs:line 79
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.Arguments.Get[T](String propertyName) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\Arguments.cs:line 18
            at lambda_method(Closure , IArguments )
            at StructureMap.Construction.BuilderCompiler.FuncCompiler`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateBuilder>b__0(IArguments args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Construction\BuilderCompiler.cs:line 56
            at StructureMap.Construction.InstanceBuilder.BuildInstance(IArguments args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Construction\InstanceBuilder.cs:line 34
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, IInstanceBuilder builder) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorInstance.cs:line 237
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorInstance.cs:line 218
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 103
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 69
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.ConstructNew(Type pluginType, Instance instance, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ObjectBuilder.cs:line 39
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance instance, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ObjectBuilder.cs:line 27
            at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 176
            at StructureMap.BuildSession.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 36
            at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 215
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.DefaultInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\DefaultInstance.cs:line 22
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 103
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 69
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Get(String propertyName, Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorInstance.cs:line 74
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Get[T](String propertyName, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorInstance.cs:line 79
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.Arguments.Get[T](String propertyName) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\Arguments.cs:line 18
            at lambda_method(Closure , IArguments )
            at StructureMap.Construction.BuilderCompiler.FuncCompiler`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateBuilder>b__0(IArguments args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Construction\BuilderCompiler.cs:line 56
            at StructureMap.Construction.InstanceBuilder.BuildInstance(IArguments args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Construction\InstanceBuilder.cs:line 34
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, IInstanceBuilder builder) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorInstance.cs:line 237
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorInstance.cs:line 218
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 103
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 69
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.ConstructNew(Type pluginType, Instance instance, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ObjectBuilder.cs:line 39
            at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance instance, BuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ObjectBuilder.cs:line 27
            at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 176
            at StructureMap.BuildSession.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 36
            at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 215
            at StructureMap.Container.GetInstance(Type pluginType) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:line 265
            at Fables.Web.DependencyResolution.StructureMapDependencyScope.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in f:\MyProjects\Fables\Fables\Fables.Web\DependencyResolution\StructureMapDependencyScope.cs:line 123
            at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 49
       InnerException:
```

Can somebody explain please, what is this exception mean and how to resolve it? Ty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your app is using the second constructor as StructureMap *will automatically select the "greediest" public constructor of a class to use for injection*. You can check this behaviour on the StructureMap [documents](http://docs.structuremap.net/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm).

So by looking at the error it looks like you are missing a mapping from `IUserStore<User>` to your `UserStore` class in StructureMap.

If you want StructureMap to use your parameterless constructor, you first need to make sure that StructureMap is creating the `AccountController` instance. Then you need to update your StructureMap registry code to specify which constructor should be used. (See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326081/multiple-constructor-with-structuremap-changing-the-scope)). This is also explained in [the documentation](http://docs.structuremap.net/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm#section3)

Answer (score 6):

The vital info is here:

```
Message=StructureMap Exception Code:  202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[[Fables.BLL.Entities.User, Fables.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
       Source=StructureMap
       ErrorCode=202
```

Structuremap doesn't know how to "build" IUserStore. In your structuremap registry you need to tell structuremap what object you want to use for IUserStore:

```
For<IUserStore>().Use<MyUserStore>();
```

Comment: hi Ozczecho, I am trying the same way but it is giving exception at GetInstance method "Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type IBackupTableStorageService, key """